# Define date parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I'm very new to creating custom reports. I need to prompt a begin date and an end date to the user in the crm, so that the result would be datas only created between those two dates.

I have three parameters to prefilter my datas (account, incident, contract) and added two date parameters in Visual Studio.

But now I'm pretty much stuck...

Any help would be great!

Edit 1: Here is a snippet of my query FETCH Xml-based:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
       <entity name="incident" enableprefiltering="1">
       <attribute name="overriddencreatedon"/>
      <attribute name="new_dateclotureincident"/>
      <attribute name="title"/><attribute name="createdon"/>
      <attribute name="new_travaileffectue"/>
      <attribute name="ticketnumber" />
      <attribute name="new_dureecumuleeactivites"/>
      <order descending="true" attribute="createdon"/>
      <filter type="and"> 
      <condition attribute="createdon" value="@Date-Debut" operator="on-or-after"/> 
      <condition attribute="createdon" value="@Date_Fin" operator="on-or-before"/> 
      </filter>
      <link-entity name="new_contrats" alias="aa" to="new_contrat" from="new_contratsid" enableprefiltering="1">
    <attribute name="new_referencecontrat"/>
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name="new_lignecontrat" alias="ab" to="new_lignecontrat" from="new_lignecontratid">
    <attribute name="new_unitesrestantes"/><attribute name="new_unitesrestantes"/>
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name="account" alias="ac" to="customerid" from="accountid" enableprefiltering="1"><attribute name="name"/>
    </link-entity></entity></fetch>
```

The dates are prompted without problem at the execution of the report but the datas are not sorted correctly after I pick them. I've just created two simple date parameters so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved !

Simple matter of date format.

After associating a date format expression with my parameters, it works perfectly !

```
=Format(Parameters!YourDateParameterName.value,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Proper solution to a very misleading problem. Thank you sir!